# Issue trying to POST` to .NET` application through HTTPS

Tags: java, .net, web-services, post

I am having an issue trying to `POST` to `.NET` application through `HTTPS`. i get the following response from the server.

```
Error while dispatching hrxml [ Server was unable to process request. --> Procedure or function 'sp__LogMessage' expects parameter '@pi_ClientID', which was not supplied.   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at DispatchService.HRISMessageRouter.MessageRouter.Route(String HRXML)
       at DispatchService.DispatchMessage.Dispatch(String HRXML)]
```

My Java code ;

```
String requestURL = "https://test.com";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        requestURL = "https://test.com/example.asp";
        params.put("name", "xxx");
        params.put("age", "88");    
        InputStream  input = HTTPUtil.sendPostRequest(requestURL, params);
        String[] r = HTTPUtil.parseMultipleLinesRespone(input);
        for (String line : r) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Comment: does that actually end in .asp?  Because .asp is not a .NET application, although your stack trace seems to indicate that it's a .net web service.

Comment: It does end with `.asp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem within the server application when it invokes a stored procedure.  Do you know that the server application works?  It doesn't look like anything you can address by changing your client.

Comment: This URL says to change the `setRequestProperty ` property. Do you think it will make a change  ? http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_23423143.html